# No puedo cambiar el valor de una variable en una funcion - Python

Tags: python, funciones, variables

Mi problema es que al intentar cambiar el valor de una variable en una función, al verificar si ha cambiado, sigue con su valor inicial.
He intentado a poner global antes de la variable dentro de la función pero el signo "=" da un error por algún motivo diciéndome que hay un error de sintaxis.

Aquí esta mi código, las variables que quiero cambiar como se puede ver en las funciones son, `local_userIdentifier` y `local_userName`.

```
#WaveTalk v1.0.0 Codigo Fuente en Espanol
print("WaveTalk v1.0.0.")

#Variables

local_lastSentMessage = ("DEFAULTLASTSENTMESSAGE") #Indica el string del ultimo mensaje enviado para enviar a otros clientes de WaveTalk
local_lastReceivedMessage = ("DEFAULTLASTRECEIVEDMESSAGE") #Indica el string del ultimo mensaje recibido para que el cliente lo obtenga
local_username = ("DEFAULTUSER") #Indica el nombre de usuario
local_connectedUsers = [] #Indica los nombres de usuario de los clientes conectados
local_userIdentifier = 0000 #Numero identificador del cliente en la red
local_networkIdentifiers = [] #Numeros identificadores en la red


#Modulos

import os
import random

#Funciones

def getIdentifier():
    local_userIdentifier = random.randint(1,4444)

def login(local_username):
    if not local_username in local_connectedUsers:
        local_connectedUsers.append(local_username)
    else:
        print("Tu nombre de usuario esta siendo ocupado, cambialo o agrega algunos numeros para entrar")
```

Comment: Por cierto, para guiarlos, trata de un programa de mensajería, obviamente no esta completo porque este problema me surgió, gracias de antemano :P

Comment: el global se usa sin signo de = , `global local_userIdentifier` y luego un `local_userIdentifier="algo"`

Comment: No entendí, podrías explicármelo con un ejemplo?